# `$stmt->execute()` Returns False but Still Inserts

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a prepared php statement to insert a row into my database. I have (what i consider) error checking along the way. At the end there is a check for an error on `$stmt->execute()`. If it returns `false` I want it to cancel the `INSERT` operation and show my message. The value is `false` but the `INSERT` is still successful. I had assumed if `$stmt->execute()===false` then there would be no `INSERT` into my database.

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I was having trouble finding a previous question similar to mine.

Here is the section causing the issue:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO login (username, password, name, branch, officer, type, alerts) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $nbadmin->prepare($sql);
    if(false===($nbadmin->prepare($sql))){
        $nbadmin->close();
        echo '<script>alert("Something went wrong; try again.")</script>';
        error();
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $user, $pass, $name, $branch, $officer, $type, $alert);
    if(false===($stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $user, $pass, $name, $branch, $officer, $type, $alert))){
        $nbadmin->close();
        echo '<script>alert("Something went wrong; try again.")</script>';
        error();
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    if(false===($stmt->execute())){
        $nbadmin->close();
        echo '<script>alert("Something went wrong; try again.")</script>';
        error();
    }else{
        $nbadmin->close();
        finish();
    }

function error(){
    header("Refresh: 0; url=../edit-user.php#user-form");
}
```

Comment: You execute the statement twice, first with `$stmt->execute();` and immediately after that inside the `if(...)`

Comment: @MatteoTassinari were you referring to the `var_dump()`? I just removed. That was there just for testing purposes

Comment: I am not referring to `var_dump`. When doing `if(false===($stmt->execute())){`, that executes the statement again! And it fails probably because there is a unique constraint on one of the fields, I would guess `username`.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I see now, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing your query twice.

In fact your code reads:

```
$stmt->execute();
if(false===($stmt->execute())){
    $nbadmin->close();
    echo '<script>alert("Something went wrong; try again.")</script>';
    error();
}else{
    $nbadmin->close();
    finish();
}
```

However, the first row of that fragmen executes the prepared statement, which is then executed **again** as part of the `if(...)` condition.

This so performs another insert, which fails, probably because there is some unique constraint on your database table, I would guess on the `username` field.

You have two possible solutions. First, you could save the result of the `execute()` into a variable, like this:

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
if(false === $result) { ... }
```

Or else you could call the method directly inside the `if(...)` statement, like this:

```
// $stmt->execute(); // remove this line
if(false === $stmt->execute()) { ... }
```

I myself would favor the first option though.

Finally, please note that you execute also `$nbadmin->prepare($sql)` and `$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $user, $pass, $name, $branch, $officer, $type, $alert)` twice, for the same reason, but those do not seem to generate an error.

Comment: A third option would be to enable error reporting and stop checking the return value altogether.

Comment: Well, I think the two things are complimentary

Comment: @Dharman That would be beneficial to me but end users probably wouldnt know what to do with the php/mysql error

Comment: Your not supposed to display errors to the end-users. Log the errors in a file on a server. PHP has an amazing error reporting capability. See [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: That is true, but you also need to tell the user whether the operation was successful, and to do so you need to check the return value.